# STL Export from Makehuman Model giving strange results?

Tags: export, 3d-printing

I'm trying to make 3D models of characters from my novels, in order to make my own 'figurines' of them via 3D printing.  I've done the first one, and there are no non-manifold edges.  At this point, before I posed the character, I did a test export just to get an idea of the cost from Shapeways.  At this point, I ran into a problem.

When I export the model to STL, the STLViewer program cannot actually open it, instead crashing and causing multiple error messages.  When I import the STL back into Blender, it is slightly deformed.  When I upload it to Shapeways, the clothes seem to have disappeared, the face is deformed, and it doesn't pass the printability checks.

This occurs regardless of whether I export just a single part of the model (e.g. the hair) or the whole thing.  What can I do to actually be able to export these models so that I can 3D print them?

I'm using Blender 2.79.

Update:
I've also tried exporting in OBJ format, with identical results.

Comment: Could you upload a .blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (and put it into your question by editing it) containing your character or an object, that has the same issues, so that we can more efficiently figure out whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I've got it worked out.  It was a question of units.  I'd scaled it in metres in Blender, but Shapeways no longer seems to accept uploads in metres, just in millimetres and inches.